# Calculate wining probability in a dart game

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

Suppose we're playing the following dart game:

The player can play up to $T$ rounds. In each round of the game, the player first throw a black dart, and then a white dart. Each dart independently hit the bullseye with probability $p$. Game continues until $K$ darts have hit the bullseye. He/she "wins" if none of the darts that hit the bullseye are white. What's the winning probability?

Here is my solution:

Suppose the player wins at $n$ th round, i.e he/she has thrown $n$ black darts and $n$ white darts. In order for the player to win at this time, all the white darts must not hit the bullseye, and the $n$ th black dart must hit the bullseye, and there must be other $(k-1)$ out of the first $(n-1)$ black darts hit the bullseye. Put it together, we have

$$Pr[Win] = \sum_{n=k}^T (1-p)^n \cdot p \cdot {n-1 \choose k-1} p^{k-1} (1-p)^{n-k} $$

i.e.

$$Pr[Win] = p^k \sum_{n=k}^T {n-1 \choose k-1} (1-p)^{2n-k} $$

But I don't a good idea to simplify this further, or upper bound it. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an extended hint rather than the full answer.

The last expression after a bit of algebra can be rewritten as 
$$
S_1 = \sum_{j=0}^{r} \binom{m+j}{m} x^j
$$
The binomial coefficient $\binom{m+j}{m} = \binom{-m+1}{j}$, so the sum is 
$$
S_2 = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \binom{-m+1}{j} (-x)^j = \frac{1}{(1+x)^{m-1}}
$$

You need to do more algebra carefully, because the last expression is for the infinite sum.

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't see why $ {m+j \choose m} = {-m+1 \choose j }$ holds. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Generalized binomial coefficient. Set $-m+1 = \alpha$ and expand $\binom{\alpha}{j}$, then plug in back $-m+1$. What do you get?

Comment: Sorry I still didn't get it. ${\alpha \choose j} = \frac{a!}{j!\cdot (\alpha - j)!} = \frac{(-m+1)!}{j!\cdot (-m+1-j)!}=?$ How is this related to $\frac{(m+j)!}{m! \cdot j!}$?

Comment: start by cancelling out the terms in alpha an then plug it in back